# How do you share code from a GitHub gist on dartpad.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart

I keep forgetting how I can share some code snippet that I uploaded to GitHub when opening issues in a repo, or when I want to quickly show some flutter code to a friend or colleague.

Answer (score 1):

Append its github gist hash to the url:

https://dartpad.dev/a1a1b1b1e3e19248699381cafe (this one is made up)

Answer (score 0):

Go into the dart file in your github, make sure the title or name of file ends with `.dart` For example:

```
Username/myflutter.dart
```

once inside, the url should be something like this

http...gist.github.com/Username/`f3ecf1904`

The last part of the url: `f3ecf1904` will be a random character and it represents the ID of your code. You just need to copy paste it next to the dartpad url:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ `f3ecf1904`

This will work with both secret and public gists.